# Ignore _load file

Tags: linux, shell-script

I have a requirement where once a file is loaded, I create a _load file for that. 
for ex:- if temp_20180101.txt is loaded, I create temp_20180101.txt_load for that.

Now in next run i wanted to ignore all those file whose _load is present in the directory and pick the latest available file.

Please advise how to do this in one linux command

Comment: I wanted to exclude both _Load files as well those files for whose  _load file is present in the direcrtory .

Comment: In first run we anyways will not have any _load file. As we are creating it once load process is complete

Comment: will have new file evey time with timestamp suufix, only thing is I just wanted to ignore the already loaded file

Comment: Please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/419552/edit) in body of your question with above comments instead , and delete your comments. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

First example (recursively find files, with `find`):

```
find . -type f -name 'temp_*.txt' -exec sh -c '[ ! -e "$0"_load ]' {} ';' -print
```

This will output the names of all the regular files in the current directory (or below) that matches the pattern `temp_*.txt` but that doesn't have a corresponding `temp_*.txt_load` file associated with it.  The loading could then be done by another `-exec` in place of the `-print`.

Second example (simpler, explicit shell loop):

```
for name in ./temp_*.txt; do
    if [ -f "$name" ] && [ ! -e "$name"_load ]; then
        command_to_load "$name"
        touch "$name"_load
    fi
done
```

This is an explicit shell loop that only looks at the files in the current directory. If the matched name is a regular file and if there is no corresponding `_load` file associated, some command to load `$name` is invoked and the `_load` file is created.

One may want to use

```
command_to_load "$name" && touch "$name"_load
```

inside the `if`-statement to only create the `_load` file if the loading went well.

Comment: @puneetgupta Good! If this solves your issue, please consider [accepting the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).